# Авторизация на олкс

Tags: python, парсер, авторизация

Помогите авторизоваться на олкс, перепробовал подставлять уже все параметры не помогает, может есть у кого решение, буду очень признателен?)

```python
import requests
from requests import Session

with Session() as s:
    
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}

    params = {
        'client_id': "87daj3ob974f0vi4gn7ljdqa8",
        'code_challenge': "kEb6atxA6TUe5RI-cIZGaI48FNhTH5vRntfNUEKsl8U",
        'code_challenge_method': 'S256',
        'state': "eyJyZWZlcnJlciI6Imh0dHBzOlwvXC93d3cub2x4LnVhXC9yZWRpcmVjdG9yXC8/dXJsPWh0dHBzJTNBJTJGJTJGd3d3Lm9seC51YSUyRmQlMkZvYnlhdmxlbmllJTJGcmF6Ym9ybnllLWdhbnRlbGktb3QtMTAtMTYtMTgtMjEtMjYtMjgta2ctZ2FudGVsaS1uYWJvcm55ZS1rb21wb3ppdG55ZS1JRE11RHpnLmh0bWwlM0Zpc1ByZXZpZXdBY3RpdmUlM0QwJTI2c2xpZGVySW5kZXglM0QxIn0=",
        'st': "eyJzbCI6IjE4NmY1MDVmODZmeDQwYTRlMDcxIiwicyI6IjE4NzlmMjZlZTU5eDU2YzMwYmYzIiwiY2MiOjB9",
    }

    
    link = "https://ua.login.olx.com/api/initiate-auth"
    data = {"auth_parameters":{"login":"+38095...","password":"...."},"user_context_data":{"encoded_data":"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"}}
    response = s.post(link, headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
    print(response)
```

Comment: data=data  --> json=data

Comment: response = requests.post(link, headers=headers, json=data) если так то ничего не помогло

Comment: На что ругается в ответе? На friction token?

Comment: ни на что не ругается, просто ответ приходит либо 400 либо 401, а должен же 200 приходить) я не могу понять, то ли ссылка может не та для авторизации, хотя я их все уже там перепробовал

Comment: @Олег ну камон, надо не только код смотреть, а содержание. Я поигрался в Firefox и Postman, там не всё так просто. Более чем уверен, что у вас такая же ошибка как и у меня получилась, та что в `encoded_data`. И если так, то надо вам заморочиться с антикапчей. А ещё, обратите внимание, вы используете сессию как `s` (впервые такое вижу, но почему бы и нет), но этот `s` нигде дальше не используете.

Comment: дело в том что я новичок, почитав документацию + немного помог знакомый с освоением, получилось спарсить несколько сайтов с авторизацией, но здесь почему то не получается. Содержание смотрел, так же смотрел Network какие параметры уходят, пробовал и подругому логиниться через сессию нормально так сказать, но ничего не выходит, с антикаптчей вообще не ставлкивался ниразу, как ее обходить или как с ней бороться не знаю. В коде немного допустил ошибку, не response = requests.post, а response = s.post, за это прошу прощения)

Comment: @Олег да ошибки — ладно, простительно ) Но сайт не такой простой. В смысле, с ним можно разобраться, но это не просто копирование ключей с браузера, даже в браузере повтор запроса через некоторое время будет нерабочим. Поэтому надо сначала получить `encoded_data` с антикапчи, запросом, библиотеками? Не важно. И потом, получив это, делать авторизацию. Иначе будут ошибки, исходя из моего недолгого анализа. Другой вариант, который я не пробовал — импортировать куки (авторизацию) с браузера, и использовать уже программно сессию.

Comment: @DiMithras да вот хз как его получить, знал бы уже сделал бы давно)) если есть мысли какие или решение рабочее не стестняйтесь, буду рад выслушать) а то я так понял я тут на долго с этой авторизацией застрял

Comment: @Олег попробую как время будет. Но если защита очень хитрая, это тот редкий случай, когда лучше использовать Selenium с undetected chrome browser.

Comment: @DiMithras ай уже не актуально, я нашел как пройти авторизацию в принципе, но там еще надо как то вытянуть номер телефона по нажатию кнопки, в общем заморочились знатно для того что бы было как можно труднее спарсить инфу)

Comment: @Олег так там же есть регистрация по e-mail без телефона )

Comment: @Олег или имеется в виду как на Авито, где надо было нажать на кнопку, чтобы показать чей-то телефон?

Comment: @DiMithras хз как на авито было, но там да надо нажать кнопку что бы телефон показать, и при нажатии данные уходять и приходит номер телефона, смотрел в Network